# How to use Inverse attributes in Android?

Tags: android, attributes, styles, android-theme

I have just noticed `R.attr` has many `<attribute_name>Inverse` attributes, for example: ([textColorPrimaryInverse](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textColorPrimaryInverse))

But I couldn't find any explanation about those attributes usage in Android application nor any articles, can someone please explain them and how they should be used?

Comment: Pretty simple, really.  Let's say you have a dark theme.  `textColorPrimary` will be a light color so you can see it against the dark background.  But maybe you have a card view that you really want to stand out, so in your dark theme this card view gets a light background to contrast against the dark container background.  In this case, you might style the text with `textColorPrimaryInverse` (a dark color) so you can see it on the light cardview.

Comment: so in your style, you have to choose the inverse style for the view, otherwise, it won't apply automatically?

Comment: For example, a text appearance style like `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Inverse` has a `textColor` of `textColorPrimaryInverse`.  It's a way to keep styles consistent.  Take a look through the `styles.xml` files, especially for AppCompat and you can get a feel for how they are put together.